# Find number of zeros in half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

$az^3-z+b=e^{-z}(z+2)$

$a>0, b>2$

Prove that the equation has two solutions in the right half plane.

I think this is an application of Rouche theorem, who can give some advice?

Thank all of you!